# How to put the button under the image in Repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am learning how to use the ASP.Net Repeater control.  Currently, my output looks like this:
[image]

My source looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" />&nbsp
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Upload" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <hr />
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
        <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Image runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" ID="image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <hr />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Url] FROM [Gallery]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
</form>
```

Now, I tried adding a button, but it doesn't quite appear where I want it to and it throws off the display:
[image]

My ItemTemplate code looks like this, now:

```
            <asp:Image runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" ID="image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCopy" Text="Copy" />
```

So, I was wondering, how I could get the button to appear under the image?  I'm guessing this could be handled by using CSS, but I'm not sure how.  Can someone offer some help?

THanks!

Comment: you didn't mention where you want the button

Comment: Heh, sorry for being obscure!  I mentioned it in the title, but I'll add it to the main question.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your item template:

```
   <div style="float:left;overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;">
                <asp:Image runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" ID="image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
                <br/>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCopy" Text="Copy" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, doing it this way makes each image appear on its own line, like in a column of images, instead of rows of images.

Comment: Sorry forgot the `display:inline-block;` in the style attribute. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Works just like I wanted.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This should put the button over the bottom left corner of the image and keep the image layout the same as in your first screenshot.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width:200px;height:200px;float:left;position:relative;margin:2px;">
        <asp:Image runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" ID="image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Url") %>' />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCopy" Text="Copy" style="position:absolute;left:2px;bottom:2px;" />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If you can't get the `<div>`'s to align properly, `<li>`'s would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `<br />` between the image and button

Comment: Hmm, doing it this way makes each image appear on its own line, like in a column of images, instead of rows of images.